# Using multiple SQL insert statements in one command to insert multiple rows to a table using a windows form in Visual Basic,

Tags: sql, vb.net

i am seeking for a set of code which would allow me to insert 8 rows of data at once in to a table in a SQL database table.

something like this,

```
        sqlur = objCon.CreateCommand()
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO RESULTS (CandidateNumber,CandidateName,VotesReceived) VALUES ('" & candNo1 & "', '" & votefname1 & "','" & votesgot1 & "');"
        'strSQL = "INSERT INTO RESULTS (CandidateNumber,CandidateName,VotesReceived) VALUES ('" & candNo2 & "', '" & votefname2 & "','" & votesgot2 & "');"
```

thank you !

Comment: This code is crazy-vulnerable to sql injection. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: Also, this will in part depend on what kind of database you're using (Access? Sql Server? MySql?), but you didn't include that with the question.

Answer (score 1):

Typically I avoid using the Values function and go with a SELECT statement if the values come from another table.

```
INSERT INTO RESULTS (CandidateNumber, CandidateName, VotesReceived)
SELECT candNo, votefname, votesgot
FROM ResultsTable
```

Comment: Modified to provide an answer.  I was trying to get more information so that I could formulate a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SQL like this:

```
INSERT INTO RESULTS (CandidateNumber, CandidateName, VotesReceived) VALUES (
    1, 'NAME 1', 100,
    2, 'NAME 2', 150,
    3, 'NAME 1', 57,
    4, 'NAME 4', 100,
    5, 'NAME 5', 28,
    6, 'NAME 6', 57,
    7, 'NAME 7', 38,
    8, 'NAME 8', 294
)
```

Comment: It is possible, but this use a wrong syntax, every set of values should be enclosed in parenthesys and not sure if it works with every database.

Comment: does not seem to work, it says the column number does not match.

Comment: yes , it started to work after i meddled around with the parenthesis, thank you so much guys